# Dividing in C# without Math class library

Tags: c#, math, loops

I have made a program that divides without any arithmetic characters, here is the code:

```
        int num1;
        int num2;

        Console.WriteLine("Enter first number");
        int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out num1);

        Console.WriteLine("Enter Second Number");
        int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out num2);
        int sum = 0;

        sum = num1;
        int counter = 0;

        while (sum > 0)
        {
            sum -= num2;
            counter += 1;
        }
        Console.WriteLine("The division of the two numbers is " + counter);
```

I would now like to make it show the remainder of a division e.g. 10 / 3 will show 1 as there is 1 left from the sum.

How would I go about doing it? What kind of loop should I use and how similar is it to my division loop?

Comment: 10 / 3 will output 3, not 1. What you mean is 10 % 3. That will output 1.

Comment: Have you tried running this program? It returns **4**!

Comment: I am using ONLY addition and subtraction,I forgot to say that

Comment: This just doesn't work. 1/100000000 = 1. 70/89 = 2.

Comment: Ah... And the math operations (+,-,*,/,%) on primitive types (int...) aren't defined in the Math library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var rem = num1;
while (rem >= num2)
{
  rem -= num2;
}

Console.WriteLine("The remainder is " + rem);
```

or if you want to make it really easy then after your loop:

```
var rem = sum + num2;
```

Since your program is flawed you should change the loop to:

```
while (sum >= num2)
{
  sum -= num2;
  counter += 1;
}
```

Then you have the division result in `counter` and the remainder in `sum`.

Comment: What if the operands are negative numbers?

Comment: @Eric Lippert: Of course that will result in undesired behaviour. The premise though seems to be that the numbers are positive if looking at the code in the OP.

Answer (score 1):

Change this line

```
while (sum > 0)
```

to this

```
while (sum >= num2 )
```

then `sum` will hold the remainder, and `counter` will actually give the correct result.

GJ

Answer (score 0):

The remainder will be `sum + num2`.

Answer (score 0):

Change the `while` in

```
while (sum >= num2)
```

and add at the end

```
Console.WriteLine("The remainder of the division of the two numbers is " + sum);
```

Answer (score 0):

I do hope this is just an exercise in seeing if you can divide without actually dividing and not a genuine attempt to make an efficient dividing algorithm!

I'd hate to see how long it takes to calculate `1,000,000,000 / 1`

Anyway, if you must do it this way, then the remainder will be the final value of `sum` plus `num2`.

Comment: Yeah its just a challenge I've set myself to

Answer (score 0):

```
while (sum >= num2 ) // <- changed
{
    sum -= num2;
    counter += 1;
}
Console.WriteLine("The division of the two numbers is " + counter);
Console.WriteLine("The remainder of the two numbers is " + sum);
```